# How to assign the VectorColorFunction to phase (instead of magnitude) in VectorPlot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, 2d-vector

I would like to plot 2D vector by assigning the color to the phase/angle of the data points (instead of their magnitude), like that color used in `ComplexPlot` function. However, ComplexPlot dose not have the VectorMarker I like to use and show the magnitude of the datapoints.

This is what I got with

`VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, VectorMarkers -> "CircleArrow", VectorColorFunction -> Hue]`

[image]

I also tried to assigne `VectorColorFunction -> ArcTan[y/x]` but this does not work.

==========Amendment after suggestions of  @mikuszefski ==============

I modified the code to
`VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, VectorMarkers -> "CircleArrow", VectorColorFunction -> (ColorData["Hue"][Arg[#3 + I #4]] &)]`

However, an error message shows "ColorData::notent: Hue is not a known entity, class, or tag for ColorData. Use ColorData[] for a list of entities."

I found an available color map "Rainbow"

`VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, VectorMarkers -> "CircleArrow", VectorColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Arg[#3 + I #4]] &)]`
Here is the result:

[image]

But "Rainbow" is not cyclic color table suitable for display angles. Anyway, it now allowed map the color according to angles (a defined function). The next step is to generate a real Hue color table which can be passed to ColorData, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Docs of `VectorColorFunction` you probably need something like that

```
VectorColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", (Pi + Arg[#3 + I #4])/ (2 Pi) ]&)
```

The `VectorPlot` automatically passes 5 arguments, which should be `x`,`y`, `vx`, `vy` and `r` i.e. the norm. so you can easily get the angle creating a complex number out of the vector components, i.e. argument 3 and 4. Hence, you have to provide the according pure function. In contrast to the example in the docs, here I rescale manually.

Info... I do not have *Mathematica* at hand right now, so I could not test the answer.

**Update**

It seems that `Hue` is not valid with `ColorData`, so I changed the above code to `Rainbow`. Looking at the [`ColorFunction` docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) to get `Hue` it should probably read

```
VectorColorFunction -> Function[ { x, y, v, w, r }, Hue[ (Pi + Arg[ v + I w ]) / (2 Pi) ] ]
```

which should be equivalent to

```
VectorColorFunction -> ( Hue[ (Pi + Arg[ #3 + I #4 ] ) / (2 Pi) ]& )
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is in that line. As a beginner user, I have not yet fully understand how to define different function for parameters. However, the example code you provide results in error message "ColorData::notent: Hue is not a known entity, class, or tag for ColorData. Use ColorData[] for a list of entities."

Comment: It appears "Hue" is not a color table native to ColorData, the closest color table is "Rainbow", however, Rainbow is not cyclic, which is not suitable for display angles. One has to generate a "Hue" color table to be compatible to ColorData.

Comment: @w4m Ok...as mentioned, I have the problem that I do not have Mathematica to test, but if I remember correctly from the older versions of Mathematica it may work directly like this: `VectorColorFunction -> ( Hue[ (Pi + Arg[ #3 + I #4] ) / ( 2 P i) ] ] & ) ` ... can you check?